# Ruby remove the implicit break in Case statement? (How to make case like Switch)

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

```
x='bob'
case x
when "bob"
puts 'it stops here'
when 'bob'
puts 'but i want it to stop here'
end
```

Is there anyway to make case statements behave like the vanilla switch? So that it'll cycle through all the "when's" before breaking out? I'm surprised that ruby has it behave almost identically like a `elsif`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be identical to stacking (not nesting) if blocks?

Comment: Perhaps a less contrived example would help. You should use the right tool for the job and I'm guessing that a `case` isn't it.

Comment: i wanted to prove that switch would have both `puts` executed. Where as `case` breaks out after the first condition is met "it stops here". Stacking if blocks is an alternative, but not pretty for more than one-liners.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Michael,

While your example is a bit misleading ('bob' matches both 'bob' and "bob" so the first case would always match), you just can use simple if's like in `if_test` method below :

```
def case_test(x)                                                  
  puts case
  when x > 3
    "ct: #{x} is over 3"
  when x > 4
    "ct: #{x} is over 4"
  end   
end     

case_test(4)
case_test(5)

def if_test(x)
  puts "it: #{x} is over 3" if x > 3
  puts "it: #{x} is over 4" if x > 4
end     

if_test(4)
if_test(5)
```

This yields :

```
ct: 4 is over 3
ct: 5 is over 3
it: 4 is over 3
it: 5 is over 3
it: 5 is over 4
```

Note that you can also use multiple statements with `when`, which might help you or not depending on your real use case :

```
def many(x)              
  case x                 
  when 'alice','bob'     
    puts "I know #{x}"
  else·                  
    puts "I don't know #{x}"                                      
  end                    
end                      

many('alice')            
many('bob') 
many('eve')
```

Yields :

```
I know alice
I know bob
I don't know eve
```

Comment: Misleading - It's done on purpose. I'm asking if there's a switch alternative. Or anyway to make case:when behave like a switch (not to break out after first found case). This is a great post, and it's clear that you spent a lot of time on it, I'll let it stew over the weekend. If there are no other answers, I'll take it.

Comment: Ok Michael, I get it. So may be you want the text to be 'but I want to stop here too'.

Comment: Yes, I think it's also useful to have it cycle through all the conditions without a break. I've been stacking if blocks, but it's not pretty by any stretch.

Answer (score 3):

No. Case statements evaluate the first `when` block whose target's `===` method evaluates to `true` when passed the comparison, and stop there.

Comment: I think ruby should provide another case/when which works like switch/case in C.